# UITextField becomeFirstResponder is not working inside dynamic cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I have UITextField inside the first cell of UITableView, whenever it changes the table is changing too. The problem is that when the table is updated the field loses first responder status and `becomeFirstResponder` doesn't make it first responder again - the keyboard disappears.

I call `[_searchField becomeFirstResponder]` in tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: but keyboard disappears anyway. Update: I tried calling becomeFirstResponder in cellForRowAtIndexPath before, it didn't work too. _searchField is an outlet property of the class of cell connected to the field.

Where should I call `becomeFirstResponder` so that field becomes first responder? Or maybe I should do it somehow differently so that field doesn't lose first responder status? I tried refreshing not the whole table, but separate sections (search field is in its own section), but it didn't work, the controller tried to show cells that didn't exist anymore, so I would prefer refreshing the whole table.

I know that I can use special search controller, but I didn't like its design, so I implemented it this way...

Thanks!

Comment: A try - create a outlet to the label and set that to be the first responder in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you are reloading the cell.

Comment: I have outlet for the field and I tried making it first responder in that method too, but it didn't work as well, I thought because it was too early, I figured didEndDisplayingCell is called when the cell is displayed, but it didn't help...

Comment: Are there other input fields? My understanding is that the keyboard should not appear until you tap onto the input field.

Comment: There are no other text fields. When I touch field, keyboard appears. When the table is refreshed, keyboard disappears (I assume because the field is the part of the table). But I need keyboard to stay (or to appear again) so that as I type into the field the table keeps updating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I should've simply called becomeFirstResponder AFTER `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the same method, instead of trying to find some method that was called after table refresh inside UITableViewCell subclass or in UITableViewController class.

I didn't do it in the first place, probably, as I didn't have the reference to the cell in the place where [self.tableView reloadData] was called.

That's what worked (SOPSearchCell is the subclass of UITableViewCell, self is UITableViewController subclass instance):

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
// make searchField first responder again
NSUInteger indexes[] = {0, 0};
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:2];
SOPSearchCell *cell = (SOPSearchCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
[cell.searchField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Don't forget you can do `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];` for slightly more readable code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for something like this :)